# "This content cannot be displayed in a frame" - SharePoint 2013 Deployment

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-hosted-app, modal-dialog, sharepoint-on-prem, adfs

I have developed a SharePoint-Hosted app which opens a new modal dialog in a list. On SharePoint Online it works without problems, but if I deploy the app on a SharePoint 2013 On-Premise system I get this error when I open the modal dialog:

[image: This content cannot be displayed in a frame Erro]

I have this code added to my .aspx-file:

`<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server"  />`

But it does not work.

Here is my CustomAction from Elements.xml:

```
<CustomAction Id="2c2b7036-4582-4238-8205-b348628c0ed9.OpenMediaDatabase"
    RegistrationType="List"
    RegistrationId="100"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
    Sequence="10001"
    HostWebDialog="true"
    HostWebDialogHeight="900"
    HostWebDialogWidth="800"
    Title="Custom Title">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add in `Elements.xml` inside `CustomAction` this?

```
HostWebDialog="TRUE"
HostWebDialogWidth="500"
HostWebDialogHeight="500"
```

**EDIT**

If you are using Cross Site Publishing try adding `<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server"/>`
inside master page like in this [link](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/The-Content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame-Display-another-SharePoint-WebApplication-inside-an-iFrame-of-our-SharePoint-Site)

Comment: Yes, I edited my question and added the code from Elements.xml

Comment: I edited my answer. Might this will help.:)

Comment: Thank you, if I add the code to master page it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

I added the `<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server"/>` inside the `ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea"` in `Default.aspx` page and the issue got resolved